# Datos A VECES no se guardan en base datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, post

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: Aparece este parte que no se que es!!!][image: Datos dentro de la base de datos][image: Estructura de base de datos M]

Tengo un sistema de actualización de datos para una página web de noticias.

Consta de un formulario para poner imagen, título, subtítulo, texto, etc. El formulario sirve, funciona correctamente, lo sé porque cuando lo uso, se actualizan las filas de mi base de datos y además puse un alert que indica que la base de datos fue actualizada al hacer `SUBMIT`, pero de repente se vuelve loca la tabla, y no se actualiza, la fila se queda vacía.

Cabe decir que todos los campos estan con `VARCHAR (1000)` y el campo `TEXTO` y `TEXTO2` estan con `LongText`.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
<?php
//Declaracion de variables
$etiqueta = $_POST["etiqueta"];
$autor = $_POST["autor"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
$subtitulo = $_POST["subtitulo"];
$texto = $_POST["texto"];
$texto2 = $_POST["texto2"];
$imagenCortesia = $_POST["cortesia"];
$imagen_nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$imagen_archivo = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$ruta = "imagenesNoticias";
$ruta = $ruta."/".$imagen_nombre;

//Crear Variables para conexion Noticias Principales
$host = "localhost";
$user = "********";
$pw = "*************";
$dataBase1 = "kautivai_DatosDeNoticias";

//========================= Consulta ============================//

//Consulta de campos llenos
if(isset($_POST['etiqueta']) && !empty($_POST['etiqueta']) &&
isset($_POST['autor']) && !empty($_POST['autor']) && 
isset($_POST['fecha']) && !empty($_POST['fecha']) &&
isset($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['titulo']) &&
isset($_POST['subtitulo']) && !empty($_POST['subtitulo']) &&
isset($_POST['texto']) && !empty($_POST['texto']) &&
isset($_POST['texto2']) && !empty($_POST['texto2']) &&
isset($_POST['cortesia']) && !empty($_POST['cortesia']) &&
isset($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])){

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $dataBase1) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");

    move_uploaded_file($imagen_archivo, $ruta);

    //Toma de datos y paso a base de datos
    mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO Noticia1(Etiqueta, Autor, Fecha, Titulo, Subtitulo, Texto, Texto2, Cortesia, RutaImagen) VALUES('$etiqueta', '$autor', '$fecha', '$titulo', '$subtitulo', '$texto', '$texto2', '$imagenCortesia', '$ruta')");

    echo "<script>
            alert('Los Datos han sido guardados, Base de datos actualizada!');
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>";

} else {
    echo "Problemas al insertar los Datos en la base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que este sucediendo?

Comment: Te recomiendo mostrar el error de la condicional, pero te recomiendo aun mas usar PDO/

Comment: Puede que tus inserciones en ocasiones sean duplicadas y sean rechazadas... lo digo porque afirmas que funciona a veces y a veces no. O a un mal manejo de las conexiones a la base de datos, que exceda el límite de conexiones permitidas... Si puedes, acostumbra a revisar el log de errores, siempre contiene información relevante de lo que está ocurriendo. También, los `isset($_POST['etiqueta']) && !empty($_POST['etiqueta']` son redundantes, `isset` evalúa ambas cosas.

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda que muestres la estructura de tu base de datos y el formulario, pues así tal cual es difícil sacar conclusiones. ¿Cuando falla te muestra algún error?

Comment: He agregado una imagen de la estructura de mi base de datos..!!

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta que no sé cual es la estructura de tu DB o el código de tu formulario para validar tipos de datos, te dejo un código el cual puedes adaptar a tus requerimientos, está obviamente comprobado.

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="insertar" id="insertar" value="Guardar" 
class="btn btn-info"/>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['insertar']))
    {
      $items1 = ($_POST['FECHA']);
      $items2 = ($_POST['CUENTA']);
      $items3 = ($_POST['OT']);
      $items4 = ($_POST['CIUDAD']);
      $items5 = ($_POST['TIPO_ACTIVIDAD']);
      $items6 = ($_POST['SUBTIPO']);
      $items7 = ($_POST['ITEM_RE']);
      $items8 = ($_POST['OBSERVACIONES']);
      $items9 = ($_POST['CANTIDAD']);
      $items10 = ($_POST['OT_RECUPERADA']);
      $items11 = ($_POST['VALOR_RE_MO']);
      $items12 = ($_POST['USUARIO']);

      //Separar valores de array
     while(true){

  //Recuperar los valores de los arreglos
        $item1 = current($items1);
        $item2 = current($items2);
        $item3 = current($items3);
        $item4 = current($items4);
        $item5 = current($items5);
        $item6 = current($items6);
        $item7 = current($items7);
        $item8 = current($items8);
        $item9 = current($items9);
        $item10 = current($items10);
        $item11 = current($items11);
        $item12 = current($items12);

        //Asignarlos a variables
        $fecha=(( $item1 !== false) ? $item1 : ", &nbsp;");
        $cuenta=(( $item2 !== false) ? $item2 : ", &nbsp;");
        $ot=(( $item3 !== false) ? $item3 : ", &nbsp;");
        $ciudad=(( $item4 !== false) ? $item4 : ", &nbsp;");
        $tipo_actividad=(( $item5 !== false) ? $item5 : ", &nbsp;");
        $subtipo=(( $item6 !== false) ? $item6 : ", &nbsp;");
        $item_re=(( $item7 !== false) ? $item7 : ", &nbsp;");
        $observaciones=(( $item8 !== false) ? $item8 : ", &nbsp;");
        $cantidad=(( $item9 !== false) ? $item9 : ", &nbsp;");
        $ot_recuperada=(( $item10 !== false) ? $item10 : ", &nbsp;");
        $valor_re_mo=(( $item11 !== false) ? $item11 : ", &nbsp;");
        $usuario=(( $item12 !== false) ? $item12 : ", &nbsp;");

        // Concantenar los valores en orden para su futura insercion

     $valores='("'.$fecha.'","'.$cuenta.'","'.$ot.'",
     "'.$ciudad.'","'.$tipo_actividad.'","'.$subtipo.'",
     "'.$item_re.'","'.$observaciones.'","'.$cantidad.'","'.$ot_recuperada.'",
     "'.$valor_re_mo.'","'.$usuario.'"),';

        // Ya que termina con coma cada fila se resta con la funcion SUBSTR la 
           ultima fila
        $valoresQ = substr($valores, 0, -1);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `facturacion_hfc`(`FECHA`, `CUENTA`, `OT`, `CIUDAD`, 
    `TIPO_ACTIVIDAD`, `SUBTIPO`, `ITEM_RE`, `OBSERVACIONES`, `CANTIDAD`, 
    `OT_RECUPERADA`, `VALOR_RE_MO`, `USUARIO`) VALUES $valoresQ";

        $sqlRes = mysql_query($sql, $conexion) or mysql_error();

        // Up! Next Value
        $item1 = next($items1);
        $item2 = next($items2);
        $item3 = next($items3);
        $item4 = next($items4);
        $item5 = next($items5);
        $item6 = next($items6);
        $item7 = next($items7);
        $item8 = next($items8);
        $item9 = next($items9);
        $item10 = next($items10);
        $item11 = next($items11);
        $item12 = next($items12);

    // Check terminator
        if($item1 === false && $item2 === false && $item3 === false && $item4 
    === false && $item5 === false && $item6 === false && $item7 === false && 
    $item8 === false && $item9 === false && $item10 === false && $item10 === 
    false && $item11 === false && $item12 === false) break;

      }

    }

        if(isset($_POST['insertar'])){
      echo "
      <scripttype='text/javascript'>location.href='ingre_hfc_exi.php'</script>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Entonces, ¿puedes explicar cual es el problema de OP, y cómo tu código lo resuelve?

Comment: A que te refieres con OP exactamente, opendb, fileopen???

Comment: Disculpa, OP es una abreviación en inglés que significa Original Poster, o sea, el autor de la pregunta.

Comment: Agregue imagenes de mi estructura de DB, Podrias revisarme a ver si hay algun error por favor?

Comment: Revisa el tipo en la estructura de la DB que tipo de dato tiene para guardar la imagen: BLOB = (65,535 bytes, 65KB)
MEDIUMBLOB = (16,777,215 bytes, 16MB)
LONGBLOB = (4,294,967,295 bytes, 4GB)

Comment: Pero no estoy guaradando la imagen en la base de datos, solo estoy guardando la ruta a la carpeta q la contiene.

Comment: Te recomiendo que realices las pruebas con el código que te puse  sin guardar la imagen, después de esto guárdala pero en la base de datos y por ultimo revisa la ruta de guardado y los nombres de la variables con la que guardas la ruta y con la que realizas la concatenación. tienen el mismo nombre.

Comment: Sigo revisando y en el `INSERT INTO` el valor de la imagen que recibes por POST es $imagenCortesia y en el input el `id` es 'imagen.'

Answer (score 1):

El problema que sufres está relacionado con un mal escapado de la consulta SQL:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO Noticia1(Etiqueta, Autor, Fecha, Titulo, Subtitulo, Texto, Texto2, Cortesia, RutaImagen) VALUES('$etiqueta', '$autor', '$fecha', '$titulo', '$subtitulo', '$texto', '$texto2', '$imagenCortesia', '$ruta')");
```

Usa las consultas preparadas de PDO o mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que te falto los puntos de concatenación en el php

**Original**

`mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO Noticia1(Etiqueta, Autor, Fecha, Titulo, Subtitulo, Texto, Texto2, Cortesia, RutaImagen) VALUES('$etiqueta', '$autor', '$fecha', '$titulo', '$subtitulo', '$texto', '$texto2', '$imagenCortesia', '$ruta')");`

**Modificado**

`mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO Noticia1(Etiqueta, Autor, Fecha, Titulo, Subtitulo, Texto, Texto2, Cortesia, RutaImagen) VALUES('.$etiqueta.', '.$autor.', '.$fecha.', '.$titulo.', '.$subtitulo.', '.$texto.', '.$texto2.', '.$imagenCortesia.', '.$ruta.')");`

Te ayudaría también usar variables, campos y tablas en minúscula estrictamente así no te equivocas al nombrar algunas cosas